# How to Create a Custom Keyboard Shortcut in DOORS?

Tags: automation, db2, keyboard-shortcuts, ibm-doors, automotive

Its very time consuming to navigate through:
example:
X->Y->Z->A->B

Can we create a Custom Keyboard Shortcut for this in DOORS?

Comment: Hi! DOORS is general requirements management, and not related to programming itself.

Comment: OH!!!
I thought as we have something like preferences in MS_Words, or so... We may also find it here, But thanks for providing info

Answer (score 0):

is this about following out-links?
If so, you could write a DXL script that opens the first out-linked module and navigates to the linked object. This script can be placed in a custom pull-down-menu. The script can be given a shortcut (accelerator key).
Script would look like this.

```
Object o = current
if (null o) error "no current object"
Link lnk
for lnk in o->"*" do {
    ModName_ targetMod
    targetMod = target lnk
    Module mTgt = read(fullName(targetMod), true)
    if (null mTgt) error "cannot open target module"
    current = mTgt
    Object  oTgt = target lnk
    current = oTgt
    break
}
```

For information of how to build menus and accelerator keys, look in DXL manual, chapter "Rational DOORS window control"

Comment: Ok! this might help in other ways